# Which sObject stores Custom Buttons?

Tags: soql, custom-button, sobject

I would like to use Workbench to query our custom buttons. What is the name of the sObject that stores them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the API Name of any object whose Id or key prefix you know using a script like the following:

```
system.debug(Id.valueOf('00b'.rightPad(15, '0')).getSObjectType());
```

You can find the Id for a custom link by clicking on it and examining the URL (the key prefix for custom buttons is `'00b'`). The name of the corresponding object is **[`WebLink`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_weblink.htm?search_text=weblink)**.